# In Java, How to make CSVReader handle commas inside a particular csv field?

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv file with entries like :

```
1,Y,"$1,200",14
```

When its read through CSVReader, I get entries like `"1","Y","$1","200","14"`. Its not treating the escaped comma as escaped, but as a normal delimiter. Is there any option that can change this behaviour ?

Comment: Did you try a double " ? Maybe this helps.

Comment: Is `CSVReader` a third-party library? Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: From [Stimpy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2439422/stimpy): Did you try a double " ? Maybe this helps.

Comment: i can't change the csv file.. I'm stuck with single "

Comment: Here're the javadocs http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.html